# c# - How to stop a timer Immediately

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a System.Timers.Timer with 100 interval. my question is that if I set enable = false in timer, is current working process in timer method stop immediately? or after method finished.

```
private void watchTags(object obj, ElapsedEventArgs handler)
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<10000;i++){
            // some works
        }
    }
private void stop_button(){
    watcher.Enabled = false;
}
```

is my loop immediately stop or after finish?

Comment: so google doesn't work on your end.. ?? come on now... for example here is a previous posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563704/c-sharp-how-do-you-stop-a-timer

Comment: @MethodMan I'm already know about that. my question is when process terminate. after finish current method or as soon as enable set to false

Comment: so explain how watchTags is being called .. you have a for loop but what are you wanting to do inside the for loop..

Comment: read some data from hardware that last about 100 ms

Comment: If your method is under time ticker event it will stop without finishing process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. as  Vijay Kumbhoje said in comments when the timer is finished , any process in watchTags method immediately ends without finishing job.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `timer.Enabled = false` would stop Timer. Its same as `timer.Stop();`

`timer.Enabled = false` = `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`

`timer.Stop();` =`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `System.Timers.Timer` you can stop like this

```
timer.Enabled = false
```

if you are using `System.Threading.Timer`, use this

```
timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite , Timeout.Infinite)
```

Or use

```
timer.Stop();
```

if you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Reference [C# - how do you stop a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563704/c-sharp-how-do-you-stop-a-timer)

Answer (score 0):

use `timer.Stop();` or `timer.Enabled = false;`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If someone in 2020 went here and see this accepted answer, it's not right. `Elapsed` event will not stop with `timer.Stop()`. This will only stop launching `Elapsed` event again, nothing else.

I think accepted answer in this thread doing it right: [c# Task cancellation when using System.Timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612247/c-sharp-task-cancellation-when-using-system-timers)