# How do Timers work in .net?

Tags: c#, timer

I activated my windows timer and tried to stop but it seems not to be working, please see my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        timer1.Stop();
}
```

It shows the message over and over again and it doesn't stop. Please give me some ideas, I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563704/c-sharp-how-do-you-stop-a-timer

Comment: this will help you to understand http://stackoverflow.com/a/4563738/5001784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the timer **before** showing the message box. Otherwise they may pile up.

There is the `System.Timers.Timer` that can be configured to be a one-shot timer, but the general approach for other timers is:

When the timer event fires, stop the timer, do your thing and then start the timer again if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to re-execute the timer n times? "For" loop with n times doesn't work.

Comment: Sure. You need a class variable like `int timerRanHowManyTimes = 0` and in every timer event, the variable is increased. Only restart the timer in its event when the value of that variable is less  than the desired number of times.

Answer (score 0):

At line `MessageBox.Show("Hello");`
The execution will stop there waiting for the user to press "OK" button, so line `timer1.Stop();`
won't be reached until user interacts with the message box, and the timer will continue to work this way.