# execute an event when current time equals to set value

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

I want to execute an event at a specific time

I added a timer with 800 ms , and in the timer event I compared between the set value and the current time
but the problem is that the event happens more than ı time,as it is shown in the photo,due to the code the messagebox must occure 1 time, but when i execute it happens 7 or more times
the code is:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, Convert.ToInt16(Properties.Settings.Default.shift_1_end_hh), Convert.ToInt16(Properties.Settings.Default.shift_1_end_min), 0);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
    int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("tttt");
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIyfk.png

Comment: If you want to stop the timer from raising any more events, disable it with timer2.Enabled = false; You can do this in that method.

Comment: The code executes every 800 milliseconds so you will get a lot of message boxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - how do you stop a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563704/c-sharp-how-do-you-stop-a-timer)

Comment: Checking for when an exact time is hit is generally a bad idea. A big interval could miss the time, and a small interval could cause multiple events as you have seen. It is better to check if the current time is _greater than or equal_ to the target time, raise the event once, then set [`Timer.Enabled = false;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is the "specific time" ? When you want to raise an event ?

Comment: ı tested the same code in other a new project and it worked normally,
but in my projrct it works wrongly with multipple messageboxes; ı m wondering the problrm from th compiler or from the assembly! @esko,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better version of your code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hours = Convert.ToInt16(Properties.Settings.Default.shift_1_end_hh);
    var minutes = Convert.ToInt16(Properties.Settings.Default.shift_1_end_min);
    var date1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
    int result = DateTime.Compare(date1,DateTime.Now);
    if (result == 0)
    { 
         timer2.Enabled = false;
         MessageBox.Show("tttt"); 
    }
}
```

Points of interest:

- Simplified the creation of `date1`
- Removed `date2` and simply use `DateTime.Now` instead
- Disabled the timer once the condition is met.

Comment: when ı used compare as time the message didnt appear, but when i converted to string and compared the messeage box appeared like the following code:

Comment: var hours = Convert.ToInt16(num_shift_1_end_hh.Value);
            var minutes = Convert.ToInt16(num_shift_1_end_min.Value);
            var seconde = 0;
            var date1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes).AddSeconds(seconde);
            var date2 = DateTime.Now;
            string date1_str = date1.ToString();
            string date2_str = date2.ToString();

            int result = string.Compare(date1_str, date2_str);
            
            if (result == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                  }

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the DateTime, you can compare `DateTime.Now.Hours` and `DateTime.Now.Minutes` with the values from your settings. I was only comparing dates since I've copied most of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find better solution [[How to compare dates in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592126/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp][1])

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (result == 0)
{ 
     if (timer2.IsEnabled)
     {
        timer2.Stop();
     }
     MessageBox.Show("tttt"); 
}
```