# How to keep reusing timer

Tags: c#, timer

I'm making a simple game on console for practice that requires a time limit each round and I've encountered a problem with trying to make it so I can use timer more than once. I have this:

```
class Program
{
    static Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
    static int t = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed1;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        t = 10;
        timer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

My thoughts were that the 2nd `timer.Start()` would get the same result as the first, but nothing happens.

```
private static void Timer_Elapsed1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    t--;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");

    if (t == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Why is the second `timer.Start()` not doing anything? How do I make it so I can use timer.Start() again and it will do the same thing as the first time? I'm using System.Timers

NVM IT DOES WORK, IM JUST DUMB LOL

Comment: Should your first timer not keep elapsing after 1000 ms? From my previous work with timers, once it is started, it will keep firing at the interval.

Comment: Which timer are you using?  There are at least 3 `Timer` classes in .Net

Comment: @Ian I'm using System.Timers

Comment: 'My thoughts were that the 2nd timer.Start() would get the same result as the first' what result are you referring to ? Why do you think you need the second call to timer.Start() ?

Comment: The `System.Timers` timer periodically raises the `TimerElapsed` event at a given interval. Calling `Start` sets a boolean to true, saying that it will raise the event, calling `Stop` sets the boolean to false, saying that it won't raise the event. Calling `Start` the second time does nothing because it's telling the time to raise the event, but it's already doing that.

Comment: @auburg the result of the first start, being the 10 "Hello!" And 1 "Goodbye!". I want the timer to stop or pause until it needs to tick again , I figured I'd have to start it up again once I need it again.

Comment: @Yummy275 Just to be sure, are you pressing Enter after the first Goodbye?

Comment: I've ran your code and it seems to work as intended i.e. if you wait for 10 seconds and let it print Goodbye and then press a key the second Start() call triggers the timer countdown again. Isn't this what you're expecting ?

Comment: OMG IM DUMB  . You're right it does work , I was smashing the enter button which caused it to end. I'm sorry for wasting your guys time ! Embarrassing haha

Comment: No worries, glad we could get it worked out

Comment: One tip - don't forget to call timer.Dispose()

Comment: @auburg I've read that it's important to do that ,but I'm curious as to when i should call it. Should call it when I'm all done using timer , or should I add it after timer.Stop()? Oh and I forgot to say thank you!

Comment: When you're done using it

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping or disabling the first timer before trying to start a second time.

[C# - how do you stop a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563704/c-sharp-how-do-you-stop-a-timer)

Comment: I thought I did that when t = 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I fell compelled to give you some disclaimers:

First, console is not the right Environment for Game Development. Neither is any of the GUI techs. For games you got XNA (pretty dated) and with .NET Core a [bunch of new Options](https://www.microsoft.com/net/apps/gaming). The important thing is that you have a [Game Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming) of some form. Or at least imitate one.

Secondly, I am unsure how well most Timers work in console apps. Most of them use callbacks wich usually require a MessageQueue - wich is a GUI feature. I guess you could try a Multithreading time, but then you have to relearn everything if you leave Console applications.

As for your code: I am unsure when the Timer tick happens since you specified no interval. But I guess either:

- never
- after the 2nd timer start

Comment: The interval is set to 1 second - Timer timer = new Timer(1000)